# re.match() multiple times in the same string with Python

Tags: python, regex

I have a regular expression to find :ABC:`hello` pattern. This is the code.

```
format =r".*\:(.*)\:\`(.*)\`"
patt = re.compile(format, re.I|re.U)
m = patt.match(l.rstrip())
if m:
    ...
```

It works well when the pattern happens once in a line, but with an example ":tagbox:`Verilog` :tagbox:`Multiply` :tagbox:`VHDL`". It finds only the last one.

How can I find all the three patterns?

#### EDIT

Based on Paul Z's answer, I could get it working with this code

```
format = r"\:([^:]*)\:\`([^`]*)\`"
patt = re.compile(format, re.I|re.U)
for m in patt.finditer(l.rstrip()):
    tag, value = m.groups()  
    print tag, ":::", value
```

Result

```
tagbox ::: Verilog
tagbox ::: Multiply
tagbox ::: VHDL
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yeah, dcrosta suggested looking at the `re` module docs, which is probably a good idea, but I'm betting you actually wanted the `finditer` function. Try this:

```
format = r"\:(.*)\:\`(.*)\`"
patt = re.compile(format, re.I|re.U)
for m in patt.finditer(l.rstrip()):
    tag, value = m.groups()
    ....
```

Your current solution always finds the last one because the initial `.*` eats as much as it can while still leaving a valid match (the last one). Incidentally this is also probably making your program incredibly slower than it needs to be, because `.*` first tries to eat the entire string, then backs up character by character as the remaining expression tells it "that was too much, go back". Using `finditer` should be much more performant.

Comment: The regex should be `format = r"\:([^:]*)\:\`([^`]*)\`"` to make it work. After the change it works fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A good place to start is the[`re` module docs](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html). In addition to `re.match` (which searches starting explicitly at the beginning of the string), there is `re.findall` (finds all non-overlapping occurrences of the pattern), and the methods `match` and `search` of compiled `RegexObject`s, both of which accept start and end positions to limit the portion of the string being considered. See also `split`, which returns a list of substrings, split by the pattern. Depending on how you want your output, one of these may help.

Answer (score 0):

[re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#findall) or even better [regex.findall](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) can do that for you in a single line:

```
import regex as re #or just import re
s = ":tagbox:`Verilog` :tagbox:`Multiply` :tagbox:`VHDL`"
format = r"\:([^:]*)\:\`([^`]*)\`"
re.findall(format,s)
```

result is:

```
[('tagbox', 'Verilog'), ('tagbox', 'Multiply'), ('tagbox', 'VHDL')]
```